# GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I've been trying to create a few components in Blazor and after adding a few in  Vs 2019 it starts throwing me this (GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest task failed unexpectedly), it happens in every time

```
<GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest
  Version="$(ServiceWorkerAssetsManifestVersion)"
  Assets="@(_ServiceWorkItem)"
  OutputPath="$(_ServiceWorkerAssetsManifestIntermediateOutputPath)">
  <Output TaskParameter="CalculatedVersion" PropertyName="_ServiceWorkerAssetsManifestVersion" />
</GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
```

Comment: I deleted the debug.log file and the error  start going away